# WPF: Update cell in datagrid when another cell is selected

Tags: wpf, datagrid

We have a DataGrid composed of DataGridTemplateColumns.
Some of the columns contain simple TextBlocks, while others use ComboBoxes.

When the user clicks on a cell with a ComboBox, we need to update a TextBlock in the same row with the current value of the clicked-on ComboBox.
This is easy enough to do when a combobox selected value changes (the property bound to the combobox updates the property bound to the texblock when the combobox's value changes), but I can't figure out how to do it when the combobox cell is merely selected.
The SelectionUnit on the datagrid is CellOrRowHeader.

I have been struggling trying to extract a value from DataGrid.CurrentCell, from within a SelectedCellsChangedEvent handler, etc., with no success.
Why is it so difficult to get the current value of a datagrid cell when it is selected?!
Any pointers would be appreciated...

Comment: Have you tried to handle DataGridCell.GotFocus event? Because when you click on a Cell it receives a focus right?

Comment: How does the value in the other cell ever get to be different from the selected value in the combobox? Is it computed or something?

Comment: @bamamanow: The GotFocus event handler has the same info as the DataGrid.CurrentCell property.    
Ed Plunkett:  There are several combobox columns in the datagrid.  The textblock cell could be updated with any of the values in any of the combobox column's cells.  The issue is updating the textblock when a combobox cell is selected, not when the combobox selected value changes.

Comment: OK, so when a combo cell in Column 0 is selected, the text cell should show what's in column 0 for that row; when a combo cell in column 1 is selected, it should be what's in column 1 for that row. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @EdPlunkett  Exactly.  And when the user selects a new value from the list, the textblock cell will be updated then, too (easily done with the bound properties).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where things went wrong for you, but this is working for me. `MyRowItem` is just a random class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

It needs some additional wiring to round-trip the values, which may get weird.

```
private void DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, 
    SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //  For multiselection, e.AddedCells is a collection of all 
    //  currently selected cells as DataGridCellInfo

    var currentCell = (sender as DataGrid).CurrentCell;

    var row = currentCell.Item as MyRowItem;

    //  Note that we're using the column header as a magic string.
    //  We could use the Tag property to make this slightly less 
    //  fragile. 
    switch (currentCell.Column.Header.ToString())
    {
        case "Combo One":
            row.TextCol = row.ComboColOne;
            break;

        case "Combo Two":
            row.TextCol = row.ComboColTwo;
            break;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemCollection}" 
    SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    SelectedCellsChanged="DataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Text" 
            Binding="{Binding TextCol}" 
            Width="120"
            />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn
            Header="Combo One"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyRowItem.BValues}}"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ComboColOne}"
            Width="120"
            />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn
            Header="Combo Two"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyRowItem.CValues}}"
            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ComboColTwo}"
            Width="120"
            />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```